# Error in the execution of a query in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I launch the following request , i get this error message :

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Could someone please help me with the right query?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       TB.[U_Budget_Key] AS [Budget Key],
       (SELECT SUM(T01.[U_Budget_XOF])
        FROM [dbo].[@BUDGET] T01
        WHERE T01.[U_Budget_Key] = TB.[U_Budget_Key]
        GROUP BY T01.[U_Budget_Key]) AS [Q8],
       (SELECT SUM(T1.[OpenSum])
        FROM OPRQ T0
             INNER JOIN PRQ1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry]
             INNER JOIN OOCR T2 ON T1.OcrCode4 = T2.OcrCode
        WHERE T1.[U_Budget] = TB.[U_Budget_Key]
          AND T1.[LineTotal] <> 0
          AND T1.[U_Budget] <> ''
          AND T0.[CANCELED] <> 'Y'
          AND T1.[LineStatus] = 'O'
        GROUP BY T1.[U_Budget]) AS [Open PR],
       (SELECT SUM(T1.[OpenSum])
        FROM OPOR T0
             INNER JOIN POR1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry]
        WHERE T1.[U_Budget] = TB.[U_Budget_Key]
          AND T0.[DocStatus] = 'O'
          AND T1.[LineTotal] <> 0
          AND T1.[U_Budget] <> ' '
        GROUP BY T1.[U_Budget]) AS [Open PO],
       (SELECT (ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TA.[Debit])
                        FROM JDT1 TA
                        WHERE TA.[Account] = T0.[AcctCode]
                          AND TA.ocrcode4 = T2.[OcrCode]
                        GROUP BY TA.[Account],
                                 TA.ocrcode4),
                       0) - ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TB.[Credit])
                                    FROM JDT1 TB
                                    WHERE TB.[Account] = T0.[AcctCode]
                                      AND TB.ocrcode4 = T2.[OcrCode]
                                    GROUP BY TB.[Account],
                                             TB.ocrcode4),
                                   0))
        FROM OBGT T0
             INNER JOIN BGT1 T1 ON T0.[AbsId] = T1.[BudgId]
             INNER JOIN BGT2 T2 ON T0.[AbsId] = T2.[BudgId]
        WHERE T2.[OcrCode] = TB.[U_Budget_Key]
          AND T2.[Instance] = 2
        GROUP BY T2.[OcrCode],
                 T0.[AcctCode]) AS [Actual]
FROM [@BUDGET] TB;
```

Comment: Don't tag spam; those were 3 **completely** different RDBMS products you tagged there. When tagging RDBMS, just tag the one you are ***really*** using. From the use of brackets (`[]`) as a delimit identifier, and the error code and message aligning with that in the documentation, I *assume* you are using SQL Server.

Comment: The error is very specifically telling you the problem too; what about the error don't you understand here?

Comment: Required reading too: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Comment: Larnu , yes i use Sql server

Comment: Exactly, the query returns more than one value. I would like to have please a correction of this one in order to be able to remove the blockage

Comment: Honestly, we have no idea what the correction is; we don't have sample data nor expected results. In truth, I suspect you have severely overly complicated the problem. The fact you has multiple references to objects aliases as `TB`, yet it's not always the same objects (not even in name, as both the table variable `@BUDGET` and the object `JDT1` have the alias) is always *very* confusing. Honestly, that query is all kinds of wrong; starting again would likely be a better choice. I doubt you need all those uncorrelated queries either. Certainly having `GROUP BY` clauses in them makes no sense.

Comment: How do you expect us to know your data, and what row to return from the subquery?

Comment: Learn to love common table expressions (`WITH x AS (...)`) to build up your queries gradually and in stages (at each step you can cut up the query and add a `SELECT * FROM x` to see your intermediate results). This workflow is a lot smoother than nesting queries inside queries inside queries.

Comment: Looks like your [Actual] subquery  returns multiple rows with different `T0.[AcctCode]`.  Which one do you want?

Answer (score 0):

This error getting only in situations where selected data must be returned one record no many records. For example:

```
-- correct
select * from examples.user_group
where user_id = (select user_id from examples.user_detail where id = 10)

-- incorrect 
select * from examples.user_group
where user_id = (select user_id from examples.user_detail where id in (5,10))


-- correct
select *, (select max(user_id) from examples.user_detail) as max_user_id 
from examples.user_group
 
-- incorrect 
select *, (select max(user_id) from examples.user_detail group by id, "month") as max_user_id 
from examples.user_group
```

Your query has the same incorrect syntax:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
            -- column 1
           TB.[U_Budget_Key] AS [Budget Key],
           
           -- column 2
           (SELECT SUM(T01.[U_Budget_XOF])
            FROM [dbo].[@BUDGET] T01
            WHERE T01.[U_Budget_Key] = TB.[U_Budget_Key]
            GROUP BY T01.[U_Budget_Key]) AS [Q8],
            
            -- column 3
           (SELECT SUM(T1.[OpenSum])
            FROM OPRQ T0
                 INNER JOIN PRQ1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry]
                 INNER JOIN OOCR T2 ON T1.OcrCode4 = T2.OcrCode
            WHERE T1.[U_Budget] = TB.[U_Budget_Key]
              AND T1.[LineTotal] <> 0
              AND T1.[U_Budget] <> ''
              AND T0.[CANCELED] <> 'Y'
              AND T1.[LineStatus] = 'O'
            GROUP BY T1.[U_Budget]) AS [Open PR],
            
            -- column 4
           (SELECT SUM(T1.[OpenSum])
            FROM OPOR T0
                 INNER JOIN POR1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry]
            WHERE T1.[U_Budget] = TB.[U_Budget_Key]
              AND T0.[DocStatus] = 'O'
              AND T1.[LineTotal] <> 0
              AND T1.[U_Budget] <> ' '
            GROUP BY T1.[U_Budget]) AS [Open PO],
            
            ---- column 5 ----
           (SELECT (ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TA.[Debit])
                            FROM JDT1 TA
                            WHERE TA.[Account] = T0.[AcctCode]
                              AND TA.ocrcode4 = T2.[OcrCode]
                            GROUP BY TA.[Account], TA.ocrcode4), 
-------- INCORRECT SYNTAX, in group by you have 2 fields, 
-------- therefore this select will be return 2 records, 2 sum(TA.[Debit] values) 
                           0) - ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TB.[Credit])
                                        FROM JDT1 TB
                                        WHERE TB.[Account] = T0.[AcctCode]
                                          AND TB.ocrcode4 = T2.[OcrCode]
                                        GROUP BY TB.[Account], TB.ocrcode4), 
                                       -------- same incorrect syntax

                                       0))
            FROM OBGT T0
                 INNER JOIN BGT1 T1 ON T0.[AbsId] = T1.[BudgId]
                 INNER JOIN BGT2 T2 ON T0.[AbsId] = T2.[BudgId]
            WHERE T2.[OcrCode] = TB.[U_Budget_Key]
              AND T2.[Instance] = 2
            GROUP BY T2.[OcrCode],
                     T0.[AcctCode]) AS [Actual]
    FROM [@BUDGET] TB;
```

In your query, in **column 5** value must be shown one value, so one record, but in this query **column 5** will get 2 records...

**RECOMMENDATION**: Typically, when writing such long, difficult queries, it is recommended that you execute sub-queries or part of select "commands" one-by-one and control results. If do this, you can write a more accurate query.